# std::stable_sort: How to choose memory-optimised algorithm over time-optimised algorithm?

Tags: c++, sorting, std, c++17, stable-sort

I wish to make use of `std::stable_sort`. The complexity of the algorithm is stated as

> O(N·log^2(N)), where N = std::distance(first, last) applications of cmp. If additional memory is available, then the complexity is O(N·log(N)). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort

In my application, memory is critical, therefore, I would prefer `std::stable_sort` to use the memory-optimised O(N·log^2(N))
algorithm, rather than the time-optimised O(N·log(N)) algorithm. 
I understand that the time-optimised version will only be chosen if it is safe
to do so (memory available). However, I aim to benchmark my application, and therefore, as memory is critical, want to benchmark the algorithm when memory consumption is lowest. As my system currently has enough memory to allocate
the buffer, it will automatically chose the O(N·log^2(N)) version of `std::stable_sort`. I would therefore like to assert to `std::stable_sort` to 
take the memory-optimised version. Is this possible?

The execution policy appears
to be a parameter that can modify the algorithm, however, it appears
to only alter the extent of parallelism.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t

Although choosing either
the parallel or sequential version may actually be choosing the O(N·log(N)) or
O(N·log^2(N)) versions respectively, this is not stated anywhere on the webpage.

I wonder if anyone has any experience in asserting this choice. If so
would they be able to provide any advice?

Comment: Read [the notes section of the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort#Notes) and you have your answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that the OP knows this, but wants to be able to choose the O(N log^2(N)) even when there is available space (I'm not entirely sure why, however).

Comment: But my problem is that the attempt will not fail; as memory will be available on my system. However, as I am trying to benchmark with the minimal possible memory, I don't want the attempt to succeed. I want the slower, lower memory version.

Comment: I wish to assert `std::stable_sort` to chose memory-optimised version over time-optimised, to clarify.

Comment: Then that is impossible, you *can not* choose which algorithm to use. The choice is not configurable, but will be made internally by the function itself.

Comment: how useful is your benchmark when you dont run it on the target system anyhow? I would expect this particular issue to have only a minor effect compared to the overall different performance

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of the function you have to make sure there is not enough memory (how much that is is unspecified and implementation specific) then you have to use debugger tools which exhausts the available memory.

Comment: @tobi303 useful. It appears the buffer is the size of the original array, so it doubles the memory consumption. So, it's rather different.

Comment: If you have that specific requirements, maybe you should consider integration your own implementation of a sort algorithm to your code base.

Comment: @moooeeeep That's Plan B if nothing comes of Plan A (`*this`)

Comment: You could use [WikiSort](https://github.com/BonzaiThePenguin/WikiSort) instead (since forcing `std::stable_sort` not to use memory is impossible). Its default C++ implementation works without additional memory and is fairly performant for an in-place stable sort. If you have some control over memory, you can also force it to work with a fixed-size buffer, which makes it more performant while avoiding dynamic memory allocations. There is also [`flat_stable_sort`](https://github.com/fjtapia/flat_stable_sort) which meets your requirements and might be included in Boost at some point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can look into your headers and see which function gets called if the extra buffer isn't available. For me on gcc it is

```
    std::__inplace_stable_sort(__first, __last, __comp);
```

This is of course not standards compliant. The __inplace_stable_sort is a helper function and is not intended to be used directly.

The call by std::stable_sort to this function is a result of the following code

```
typedef _Temporary_buffer<_RandomAccessIterator, _ValueType> _TmpBuf;
  _TmpBuf __buf(__first, __last);

  if (__buf.begin() == 0)
std::__inplace_stable_sort(__first, __last, __comp);
  else
std::__stable_sort_adaptive(__first, __last, __buf.begin(),
                _DistanceType(__buf.size()), __comp);
```

Comment: So the solution would be to call this function directly, in my source code? Rather than leaving `std::stable_sort` to make the choice?

Comment: That is my suggestion, but please realize you are entering dragon infested territory. This function is not required to be there in your next compiler version.

Comment: Hmm, i'll probably give that one a miss then. Thanks for the offer though. :-)

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak May that not be good enough for your benchmarking needs, though? Given that benchmarking itself is inherently implementation-specific? Assuming you use libstdc++, that is.

Comment: What this answer says is correct, but I want to clarify something that might be misunderstood. `std::__inplace_stable_sort(__first, __last, __comp);` **absolutely is** standards compliant. Names like that are reserved **for use by the implementation** so that they can be used by the implementation without interference from (or interfering with) outsiders. It's **using those names in your code** that can have unpredictable results.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak -- don't let fear of dragons scare you off. Try it. If it works, it works. If you change compilers and it doesn't work, then you have to find another solution. But this is the easiest way to go. Don't make extra work for yourself.

Comment: If you do use this, a comment is *required*. Otherwise, when it inevitably breaks, the maintainer is justified in coming after you with murder in her eyes. Explain the what *and* the why.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately there is no standard way to tell `stable_sort` to do the in-place sort.  In C++14 the only options we have

```
template<class RandomAccessIterator>
void stable_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last);

template<class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
void stable_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp);
```

C++17 added versions that allow the execution policy as you point out but those will not affect the decision either.  If we look at the complexity requirement in [stable.sort] we get

> *Complexity*: It does at most `N log²(N)` (where `N == last - first`) comparisons; if enough extra memory is available, it is `N log(N).`

So it is mandated to use more memory if it is available.

You're either going to have to write your own and you can see [Worst case O(*n*ln*n*)O(*n*ln⁡*n*) in place stable sort?](//cs.stackexchange.com/q/2569) about that or find a library that provides the function for you.

Comment: Yep, that looks like the consensus. I think i'll have to write myself. Cheers.